# Deleting Large number of files from a folder in linux

Tags: filesystems, solaris

I am working on a linux production environment where there are about 20 million marker files existing in a folder and these are increasing at the rate of about 10,000 per day.
I need to perform cleanup on this folder and delete all files older than 5 days.
I cannot delete the entire folder as it is an active production environment and is mounted on other servers as well.
I tried using a find command as below

find /dirpath -name "*.fileExtension" -mtime 5 | xargs rm {}

and I also tried

find /dirpath -name "*.fileExtension" -mtime 5 | exec rm {}

but the rate at which these commands delete the files is very slow.
Is there a faster way to perform this activity.

Comment: How often are you performing this operation?  Once per day, or on a schedule?

Comment: I need to clear out the huge backlog of files and once that is done I will be running this once a day.

Comment: Why don't you instead automate it and run on a cron schedule multiple times per day?

Comment: I do intend to schedule it on a cron schedule, but as it is a production environment, I can only run it at a specific time. The bigger issue I am facing right now is getting through the backlog as even if I run the script throughout the day, the find command is slow because of there being continuous activity in that folder from other servers and new files are being created very fast. I need to figure out a way to get through the backlog files and then I can schedule a day to day processing.

Comment: It sounds like you have two problems.  (Well, three, really.  Putting 20 million files in a directory is just a terrible thing to do.)  First, you have lock contention during read, and second, you have lock contention during delete.  You can't eliminate the latter, but you might be able to do something about the former.

Comment: Do you have time to clean it in a few days? First `-mtime 300`, next `-mtime 200`. Use a switch on `date +%d` to determine which one if you do not want to change the script every day.